# Develop Angular2 Application with real server APIs

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-server

I have a real server with REST APIs ready. Now I am developing an angular2 web application and want to consume real REST APIs in the development phase of the web application.

I am using angular-cli.

My server does not support cross origin access so I can not access the server REST api directly.

I need some way to put a request/response handler for my webpack development server.

It may be a silly question as I am trying nodejs world first time.

Comment: You need another server that forwards to your server with the REST API if you can't configure that server to support CORS.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yeah, that is why I am talking about some way to put simple request/response handler (kind of proxy for real server) into webpack dev server.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'cors' library to allow cross origin in your server

link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

$ npm i -S cors

var cors = require('cors');

if you use express for example you should call 'use' function with cors:

app.use(cors());

Yair

Comment: I can not configure server, as it is third party server and I access to API only

Answer (score 0):

Based on suggestions I written a proxy http handler with CORS enabled. This will simply take the request from the application and delegate to the actual server. Response from the actual server will be sent back to requesting web application.
From the web application send the requests by just changing the base URL of server.
Eg. instead of **http://your_real_server.com/dashboard** use **http://localhost:7000/dashboard**

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var remoteUrl = 'your_remote_server_base_url_without_http.com';
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");

    pathName = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    query = url.parse(request.url).query;

    if (query != null) {
        pathName += '?' + query;
    }

    console.log('Remote URL : ' + remoteUrl + pathName);

    var options = {
        host: remoteUrl,
        path: pathName,
        method: request.method
    };

    http.request(options, function (res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var str = '';

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/json' });
            response.write(str);
            response.end();
        });
    }).end();


}).listen(7000, function () {
    console.log('\n=============================================================');
    console.log('================== Running at port 7000 ======================');
    console.log('=============================================================\n');
});
```