# Angular CORS with Amazon Product API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, cors, mean-stack

Created a MEAN stack app and I have an angular component that on page load is making a request to the Amazon Product API. I am running and testing locally on localhost (node/express backend).

Here is the basic request code in my component:

```
getAmazonTackle(amz:amazonservice) {
var req:Object = {
  method: this.amazonservice.Method,
  url: this.amazonservice.Endpoint, 
  headers: {
    //"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
  },
  data: this.amazonservice.Data,
  withCredentials: false
}
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req)));
this.$http(req).then(
  function(response) {
    console.dir('The response: '+response);
  },
  function(response) {
    console.dir(response);
    console.dir('The error:'+response);
  }
)
```

}

When I don't have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, accessing the page in browser I'm presented with the following in the Chrome dev console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

When I add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, I receive the following:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What I'm trying to determine is if I'm doing this incorrectly or if the amazon API doesn't support CORS.

Comment: did your problem is solved or not?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue and found that if I create cors enabled http handler that will work as middleware between your server and amazon server. This way we can solve this cors issue.
It is quite simple to create and I already written it.

[Develop Angular2 Application with real server APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383044/develop-angular2-application-with-real-server-apis)

Check out the question and the answer in the above post. 
Similar code I posted on github, if need I will share the location.

Note: As of now I handled the get request but adding other methods is fairly easy.
https://github.com/Anil8753/CORSHttpHandler